# Fetch CSS rules in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want the rules of CSS to be fetched and displayed in drop down. For this I am doing:

```
var opnr = window.opener ; 
function getStyle() { 
    var selCss=opnr.document.getElementById("CSS");
    loadjscssfile("css/"+selCss.value,"css");
    var cssRef = document.styleSheets[0];
    cssRef.href ='css/'+ selCss.value;
    var classes = cssRef.rules || cssRef.cssRules ;
    var select = document.getElementById('stylefieldid');//document.createElement('select');
    
    for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) { 
       var option = document.createElement('option');
       var className = classes[x].selectorText;
       if(className.startsWith('.')){
           className = className.substring(1,className.length);
       }
          option.text = className;
          option.value = className;
       select.add(option);
    } 
} 


function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    var fileref; 
    if (filetype=="js")
    {
        fileref=document.createElement("script");
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    } 
    else if (filetype=="css"){
        fileref=document.createElement("link");
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
    } 
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

But this is showing abrupt behaviour the variable `classes` comes to be undefined sometimes while it has value sometimes... I tried alerting `cssRef.href`  it gives me correct value..

The code is not at all working on FF. Is there any workaround?

Why is it happening like this?

Is there any alternative in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it using css parser on server side and passed the list to jsp page... and is working on all modern day browsers..

Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code is firing after the page has loaded?  Try calling it after your code in the `<body onload="someFunction()">` or at the bottom of the page

Comment: function is getting triggered.. the problem is with the code i guess. and its not working on ff at all